# Apportable Release build is not running on devices running Android prior to v4.4

Tags: android, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, apportable

Currently I am facing a strange problem with my Apportable Indie SDK. I was able to *compile and build my current Cocos2d V3.x project* 
using the command line tools with the starter pack. This build was running perfectly on devices *running Android v4.2.1 or later*. But upgrading 
to Indie version, my SDK is building the project successfully but *the APK runs only on devices running Android 4.4 or higher*. In case of devices running 
Android prior to v4.4, it only shows the splash screen, after that screen goes blank. I have faced the same problem with the Indie SDK even when working with
the *template project of Cocos2d v3.x*. I have also created a topic against this issue in [Apportable Forum](http://forum.apportable.com/t/apk-file-is-not-running-on-devices-prior-to-android-v-4-4-after-upgrading-to-indie-version/1228).

Is this Indie SDK designed to only support Android v 4.4 or later?

**Apporatble SDK Version Details:**

```
Apportable SDK version release_1.1.17 (b7aece46b817ec41a574fb012c5e3185cf055ad2 indie)
adb version cd96bfaea0f38a2de67e478463b24a4394be2cb3
android-ndk version r9c.3
android-sdk version r22.3.1
apportable-android-helper version aa719ae962ceb4890e6ce57376c883e2e57d26f5
binutils version df53d37dc178ff53f13827ea929ea89ce0d22446
ccache version c0b40b8b634ff966a097598447317a9f7754a53a
clang version f60f22f3d9f3f51d87bf01ce6da001d724d666ab
gdb version b5f29d65da6903ad0570d0c4a887c513367d2778
m4 version e447db581a4b3d4655ad62ea85d0445342c4ac6a
ninja version 315d897710c6ca6e7df7d3b0bf68879356841c5d
profiler version 4ea9b916652b70ede4bc206a462596a24e02fd14
vorbis-tools version 0c2e4c653c107b53e366ad8d352839dfca8495b0
zipbuilder version 9fdeb23bd4b05cedba3883420043a9a922807356
```

Comment: The Indie SDK supports Android v2.3 and later. Add details from logcat and/or the debugger about the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much @Paul Beusterien for your support. For better clarification I am sharing my project as well as Android Device System details. 
1. Device Details: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rodhrdad9b4ws30/Screenshot_2014-09-20-19-16-39.png?dl=0
2. Apportable Log : https://www.dropbox.com/s/fmg2p6698rqnexb/Apportable%20Log.rtf?dl=0
3. Compressed Project : https://www.dropbox.com/s/eiiq4prgb7kgsd7/Cocos2dTest.zip?dl=0
4. Android Project Details in .apportable folder: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sj29bh9m8vyqs8q/Cocos2dTestDebug.zip?dl=0